# Python StanfordNLP package errors on importing the library

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

I just installed the python stanford nlp which went fine :-

pip install stanfordnlp

from a python shell, I am trying to instantiate the package and I get the following error :-

```
>>> import stanfordnlp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/shivajidutta/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stanfordnlp/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from stanfordnlp.pipeline.core import Pipeline
  File "/Users/shivajidutta/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stanfordnlp/pipeline/core.py", line 9, in <module>
    from stanfordnlp.pipeline.doc import Document
  File "/Users/shivajidutta/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stanfordnlp/pipeline/doc.py", line 175
    return f"<{self.__class__.__name__} index={self.index};words={self.words}>"
                                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: stanfordnlp is for python 3.6 and 3.7

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
return f"<{self.__class__.__name__} index={self.index};words={self.words}>"
```

Indicates that the package is intended for Python 3.6 or higher.  It is returning an f-string, which was introduced in version 3.6.  You are running on version 2.7.

Time to upgrade?

Comment: Yes. I am on python 2.7
Thanks for the answer.